# Metal fragment shader uv coordinates change when reading in vertex color

Tags: ios, macos, shader, metal, metalkit

I was playing with applying dithering to a simple colored quad, and found a strange issue. I have a fragment shader which should calculate dithering at some `uv` and return a dithered color. This works fine on a textured quad, but strangely enough, when I access color data from my `inVertex`, the `uv` coordinates change to some bizarre values, and `y` value seems to be mapped to `x` axis. I'll try to illustrate what happens when I change stuff around the fragment shader code.

```
fragment float4 fragment_colored_dithered(ColoredVertex inVertex [[stage_in]],
                                              float2 uv[[point_coord]]) {
        float4 color = inVertex.color;
        uv = (uv/2) + 0.5;
        if (uv.y < 0.67) {
            return float4(uv.y, 0, 0, 1);
        }
        else {
            return color;
        }
    }
```

Produces the following result: [image]

Where the left side of the image shows my gradient quad, notice that `if (uv.y < 0.67)` maps to x values in the image .

If I change this fragment shader and nothing else in the code, like so, where I `return float4(0, 0, 1, 0)` instead of `inVertex.color`, the `uv` coordinates are mapped correctly.

```
fragment float4 fragment_colored_dithered(ColoredVertex inVertex [[stage_in]],
                                          float2 uv[[point_coord]]) {
    float4 color = inVertex.color;
    uv = (uv/2) + 0.5;
    if (uv.y < 0.67) {
        return float4(uv.y, 0, 0, 1);
    }
    else {
        return float4(0, 0, 1, 0); //return color;
    }
}
```

Produces this (correct) result: 
[image]

I think I can hack around this problem by applying a 1x1 texture to the gradient and using texture coordinates, but I'd really like to know what is happening here, is this a bug or a feature that I don't understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you using `[[point_coord]]`? What do you think it represents?

Unless you're drawing point primitives, you shouldn't be using that. Since you're drawing a "quad", and given the screenshots, I assume you're not drawing point primitives.

I suspect `[[point_coord]]` is simply undefined and subject to random-ish behavior when you're drawing triangles. The randomness is apparently affected by the specifics (such as stack layout) of the fragment shader.

You should either be using `[[position]]` and scaling by the window size or using an interpolated field within your `ColoredVertex` struct to carry "texture" coordinates.

Comment: thanks for that, I'll try to add a field for "`texCoord`" and see what happens with that. Reading the spec again, I have misunderstood the `point_coord` attribute for something that behaves like a uv coordinate!

Comment: Added an additional field, that worked like a charm, thanks again for pointing me to the obvious :)